# Drupal 7 - REST API - Create Alias

Tags: xml, rest, drupal, drupal-7

We need to create the node using REST API.
The sample xml to create node is as below

```
<node>
  <type>article</type>
  <language>und</language>
  <title>This is my new title </title>
  <body>
    <und is_array="true">
      <item>
        <value>this is body</value>
        <summary></summary>
        <format>filtered_html</format>
      </item>
    </und>
  </body>
  <path>http://Drupal_server/drupal/testpage</path>
</node>
```

It is creating the new node in Drupal, we not creating Alias.
If I manually create the content and add alias into it and then check the xml, then it has proper url in **PATH** tag.
Can anyone please tell, what is incorrect in above xml ?